# In VHDL, how to initialize MSB's of std_logic_vector to zeros and LSB's to a std_logic_vector literal such as "10101111001"

Tags: vhdl

In VHDL, how to initialize MSB's of std_logic_vector to zeros and LSBS to a std_logic_vector literal such as "10101111001".  I'm thinking its something like this... of course its a syntax error:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb is
end entity;

architecture beh of tb is
begin

    process

        -- ERROR!!!
        variable p : std_logic_vector(1000 downto 0) := (
            (others => '0'),
            "10101011111000011010101"
        ); 

    begin
    end process;

end architecture;
```

Answer (score 2):

The rules for aggregates are troublesome.   Instead, I recommend avoid their issues here by using concatenation:

```
variable p : std_logic_vector(1000 downto 0) := 
    (1000 downto 23 => '0') & "10101011111000011010101" ;
```

You can avoid counting (number of lower bits) by:

```
constant C : std_logic_vector := "10101011111000011010101" ;
variable p : std_logic_vector(1000 downto 0) := 
    (1000 downto C'length => '0') & C ;
```

Answer (score 1):

Using -2008:
See IEEE Std 1076-2008 9.3.3.3 Array aggregates

Prior to -2008 an association would be of the element type of the aggregate type, here std_logic. In -2008 the association can be of the type of the aggregate itself as well, here std_logic_vector. A choice must be static:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb is
end entity;

architecture beh of tb is
begin
    process
        constant lb: std_logic_vector := "10101011111000011010101";
        variable p : std_logic_vector(1000 downto 0) := (
            lb'reverse_range => lb, others => '0'
        ); 
    begin
        report lf & ht & "p(lb'reverse_range) = " & 
        to_string (p(lb'reverse_range));
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

And that produces:

```
%: ghdl -a --std=08 tb.vhdl
%: ghdl -e --std=08 tb
%: ghdl -r tb
tb.vhdl:16:9:@0ms:(report note):
    p(lb'reverse_range) = 10101011111000011010101
%:
```

The string literal is assigned to a constant of the type of the aggregate (the type of p). Without specifying the range it will be an ascending natural range (the index type of std_logic_vector). If my eyes didn't go square counting elements in the string literal that would be 0 to 22, but getting it right doesn't matter. lb'reverse_range gets it right and it's a static range.

And if you're willing to determine the length of the string literal as well as it's location in p:

```vhdl
architecture beh of tb is
begin
    process
        variable p : std_logic_vector(1000 downto 0) := (
            22 downto 0 => "10101011111000011010101", others => '0'
        );
    begin
        report lf & ht & "p(22 downto 0) = " &
        to_string (p(22 downto 0));
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

which gives us the now familiar result.

```
%: ghdl -a --std=08 tb.vhdl
%: ghdl -e --std=08 tb
%: ghdl -r tb_string
tb_string.vhdl:14:9:@0ms:(report note):
    p(22 downto 0) = 10101011111000011010101
%:
```

Using any VHDL revision (the hard way):

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity tb is
end entity;

architecture beh of tb is
    function to_string (inp: std_logic_vector) return string is
        variable image_str: string (1 to inp'length);
        alias input_str:  std_logic_vector (1 to inp'length) is inp;
    begin
        for i in input_str'range loop
            image_str(i) := character'VALUE(std_ulogic'IMAGE(input_str(i)));
        end loop;
        return image_str;
    end function;
begin
    process
        variable p : std_logic_vector(1000 downto 0) := (
            22|20|18|16 downto 12|7 downto 6|4|2|0 => '1', others => '0'
        ); 
    begin
        report lf & ht & "p(22 downto 0) = " & 
        to_string (p(22 downto 0));
        wait;
    end process;
end architecture;
```

Which produces:

```
%: ghdl -a tb.vhdl
%: ghdl -e tb
%: ghdl -r tb
tb.vhdl:23:9:@0ms:(report note):
    p(22 downto 0) = 10101011111000011010101
%:
```

the same transformation but is much more cumbersome, where you've separately provide a list of elements that will be set to '1' (and requires you to actual count the index values, and yes the indexes had to corrected to get them right while proof reading this answer). Note the choices are still static.  Here the choices are all of the element type of p.

And of course you could assign the initial value to all '0's and as a first statement assign the range of p to the value of the string literal to avoid defining the choices.

Answer (score 0):

Would be nice if I could initialize with a std_logic_vector string... but apparently this only works one bit at at time:

```vhdl
variable p :std_logic_vector(1000 downto 0) := (
   32 downto 25 => '1',
   24 downto 14 => '0',
   13 downto 0  => '1',
   others       => '0'
);

variable p :std_logic_vector(1000 downto 0) := (
   0   => '1',
   1   => '0',
   2   => '1',
   3   => '1',  
   ...
   56  => '0',
   others => '0'
);
```